# messagebox after progress bar value is 100%

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I made a progressbar but i want my tkinter program to show a messagebox when the value is 100%, can someone help me?

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

def start_bar():
    progress_bar.start(100)
    progress_bar.after(100,check)

def check():
     if progress_bar['value'] == 100:
        messagebox.showinfo("Completion Message", "Progress bar is complete.")


root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
root.title("progressbar")

progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root,orient=HORIZONTAL,mode="determinate",length=300)
progress_bar.pack(pady=20)

Button(root,text="start", command=start_bar).pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

i put my code in so you can see what i tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another call to `progress_bar.after(100, check)` inside the `check()` function so it calls itself periodically and polls the value of the progress bar

```
def check():
     check_poll = progress_bar.after(100, check)  # poll the progress bar 10x/sec
     if progress_bar['value'] >= 99:
        progress_bar.after_cancel(check_poll)  # stop polling
        progress_bar.stop()  # stop incrementing the progress bar
        messagebox.showinfo("Completion Message", "Progress bar is complete.")
```

*EDIT* - after testing, it looks like the bar never actually hits 100, so you'll want to break at `>= 99` instead. Or alternatively, you could use either `if not progress_bar['value']` *or* (perhaps more "correctly/Pythonically") `if progress_bar['value'] == 0` which will trigger when the bar loops around again to 0.